# install mobileprovision file - Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, installation, addition, mobileprovision

I know this is simple, but I've read through all the questions and there doesn't seem to be a simple answer to this.

I've created an appID. I've created a mobileprovision file, downloaded it and double clicked it and that all seems fine. (I have xcode 6)

I wan't to select my distribution profile in Code Signing Identity in the build. But all my certificates are grayed out:
(No cretificate found)[check profile]. - check profile is the name of my mobileprovision file.

How do I get this profile though to show up in XCode? and where would it show up?

Answer (score 2):

Full description is here:

Set the project level code signing build settings to their defaults:
Navigate to the Project > Build Settings tab.
Set the Provisioning Profile build setting to Automatic for all build configurations.
Set the Code Signing Identity build setting:
Set to iOS Developer for all build configurations in iOS projects.
Set to Mac Developer or Developer ID, as appropriate, for all build configurations in OS X projects.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1814/_index.html